# Can I have multiple minor versions of python as well with pyenv and tox

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, tox, pyenv

I installed python 2.6.9, 2.7.10, 2.7.11, 2.7.12 with Pyenv, but when I check ~/.pyenv/shims/, it has only one python2.7 which points to 2.7.10.
My system has python 2.7.13 installed.

When I use tox to use py2710, py2711, py2712, it uses system's python that is 2.7.13 to create virtualenv.

My paths have ~/.pyenv/shims/ before /usr/local/bin where my system python is located.

If I use py26 in tox.ini, it uses python 2.6.9 from pyenv to create virtual env.

Is there a way to handle such situation ?